# System reset(crash)during PL353 NAND controller initialization when Data-Cache is enabled in CR4 based system,

Tags: datacachefactory

I have come across a system crash during the `PL353 NAND controller` initialization, if `D-cache` enabled in `cortex-r4 based micro controller`. The `NAND chip` interfaced with `ARM’s PL353 Static Memory Controller`, and `SMC` is connected to main `matrix bus` through `AXI bus`. The driver initialize the controller and does some basic communication (`write and read of predefined data`). The NAND driver works fine with `d-cache disabled`, whereas the system get crash during NAND controller initialization, when `D-cache is enabled`.

The issue is resolved with workaround of enabling `MPU`, and defining memory region for `NAND device memory map`. I am unable to understand the behavior. Its hard to debug the issue, as the debugger losing connection after crash (cannot load PC register error is reported).

**Note: The system getting crash after sending AXI command to NAND controller.**

Please let me know how can I debug or get hint of the issue to resolve or else please let me know what is going wrong.